# concept/name extraction rules

Tags: nlp, grammar

I'm doing an NLP research, trying to extract concepts/names from phrases, I need your help defining all rules for doing so, so i can feed them onto the computer.

example rules I observed:
*if a preposition is followed by a Noun, then that noun is a concept*

- ex:*in toshka, it's always sunny*
  **Concept**: toshka

*if  Verb, 3PS present is followed by Noun, then that Noun is a concept*

-ex: *how old is Ron ?*
 **Concept**: Ron

an so on, notice that i can't take all nouns blindly, consider this example:
*when will the dark knight rises be released ?*
the concept here is **the dark knight rises**, which is not a noun.
hope my question is clear, I need all language/grammar rules that you (as a human) use to identify entities.

Comment: What about "in the tree"? Isn't 'the tree' a concept? If not then you need to be much more detailed as to what you mean by 'concept'.

Comment: you are correct mitch, for me, "tree" IS a concept

Comment: Why isn't _the dark knight rises_ considered a noun? Isn't it a name just like _Ron_?

Comment: that's the point, you know it's a noun because you know the movie, but imagine someone doesn't, how is he to know that TDKR is a concept from its position in the above phrase? that's what i'm looking for

Answer (score 1):

I was thinking about your "The Dark Knight Rises" example and I was thinking "well, if it was properly capitalized then it's obvious that it's a title of something." Then I thought "but it wasn't capitalized and I still knew. How can I tell it's a title, even if I didn't have real world knowledge that it's a movie?"

One of the ways I can tell it's a title is because of the way it's embedded in sentence. On the surface it's an embedded CP but it is taking the place of a DP. That got me thinking about how syntax might help you.

I think you should read about the double object construction. The current view of double objects was first put forth in ["On Double Object Construction" by Larson (1988)](http://www.jstor.org/discover/10.2307/25164901?uid=2&uid=4&sid=21101218033001). I can't find a full version online for free but [these lecture notes](http://www.bcs.rochester.edu/cls/s2001v2n1/runner_urwpls_v2n1.pdf) that I found should give you the main ideas.

If you generate a syntax tree it should be easy to pick out the arguments you want. Although I have never used it before today, I've been playing around with [the Standford Parser](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/lex-parser.shtml) and it looks like you might be able to adapt it to your needs.

Incidentally, the Stanford Parser was able to identify "the dark knight rises" as an NP:

```
(ROOT
  (SBARQ
    (WHADVP (WRB when))
    (SQ (VBZ does)
      (NP (DT the) (JJ dark) (NN knight) (NNS rises))
      (VP (VB come)
        (PRT (RP out))))
    (. ?)))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also look into the [ANTLR parser](http://www.antlr.org/).

Comment: Could you elaborate and write a few paragraphs on the content of that link? Link-only answers are discouraged on the StackExchange network..